# using a router plugged in to ubuntu pc to connect wirelessly to another modem/router

Tags: wireless, internet, router

PLEASE

How do I use my router to connect to another modem wirelessly so that I can use the internet.

My pc has a weak connection but I have a spare router that has a good wireless capability, I want to use it like a virtual router to access the modem upstairs so I can go online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking this is not Ubuntu related :)

You should be able to use your old router as a bridge repeater . 
There is a lot of documentation on the net, for instance:

*What is Bridging Mode in Wi-Fi Networking?*
http://compnetworking.about.com/cs/wirelessproducts/f/apbridgingmode.htm

*How to Extend Your Wi-Fi Network With an Old Router*
http://lifehacker.com/how-to-extend-your-wi-fi-network-with-an-old-router-915783308

edit:
*You will notice a speed decrease as when bridged you will use twice the bandwidth.*